# How to perform thinning/skeletonization morphology operation on GEE?

Tags: google-earth-engine, digital-image-processing

In google earth engine (GEE) they provide a morphological operator for erode and dilate as follows (Ref: [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/image_morph))

```js
image
    // Perform erosion
    .focal_min({kernel: kernel, iterations: 2})
    // Perform dilation
    .focal_max({kernel: kernel, iterations: 2})
```

As of right now I am using `ee.Algorithms.CannyEdgeDetector` to perform edge detection and aggregate over several channels using `mean` operation. Then I use OTSU's method for binarization (Ref [here](https://medium.com/google-earth/otsus-method-for-image-segmentation-f5c48f405e)) to get final binary edge

However, binary edge is too thick, and I want to perform thinning/skeletonization operation over final edge operation. I did some googling and I am not sure of its implementation on GEE. I found that there exists several algorithms (Ref [here](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_skeleton.html), [here](http://ceng503.cankaya.edu.tr/uploads/files/file/Digital%20Image%20Processing-6(1).pdf), and [here](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/thin.htm))

This lead me to my original question on how to perform such operation?

For current example implementation can be found [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/567e48d946c78720c1d5df8bb0596ea1)